# Wieso wird die "Gesellschaftliche" Moral groß geschrieben?

Tags: grammar

Wenn ich "die Gesellschaftliche Moral" schreiben würde, wieso wäre "Gesellschaftliche" groß geschrieben?

Handelt es sich hierbei um Nominalisierung? Ich dachte, dass in diesem Fall der Artikel sich auf das Nomen "Moral" bezieht.

Comment: Wo wird es großgeschrieben? Ich würde es immer kleinschreiben.

Comment: @clinch & OP: Ich habe es auch noch nie groß geschrieben gesehen.

Comment: Ging es wirklich um die gesellschaftliche Moral oder vielleicht um einen Text, dessen Titel zu „Gesellschaftliche Moral“ gekürzt wurde?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sowas wird nur großgeschrieben, falls es ein fester Term oder ein Eigenname ist, also beispielsweise in "Zweiter Weltkrieg" oder "die Großen Seen (in Amerika)". Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, wo beziehungsweise in welchem Kontext die gesellschaftliche Moral ein fester Term wäre.

Comment: Es kann auch in wissenschaftlichen Dokumenten in dieser Form vorkommen, wenn zuvor eine Definition für "Gesellschaftliche Moral" (im Gegensatz beispielsweise zur "Persönlichen Moral" - welche dann auch definiert werden müsste) gegeben wird.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Eventuell, wobei ich aber bezweifle, dass eine Definition in einem wissenschaftlichen Dokument einen Begriff bereits zu einem festen Term werden lässt. Eher kann ich mir noch vorstellen, dass ein Buch oder dgl. zum Thema gemeint ist.

Comment: Nicht als allgemeingültigen festen Begriff, aber im Rahmen der wissenschaftlichen Abhandlung selbst ist das schon gängig.